# Zurb orbit in modal window not resizing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Trying to include Foundation Zurb's Orbit feature inside a modal. The modal need to resize for each slide.

Currently it's resizing to the maximum height of the largest slide (i.e. the entire modal window). Instead I need to target the `<li class="active">` and resize the modal window to fit that element.

```
<script>
$('#introModal').on('opened', function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});

$("#introModal").on("after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit", function(event, orbit) {
  console.info("after slide change");
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
</script>


<div class="row">
  <a href="#" data-reveal-id="introModal" data-reveal class="button radius">Click For Modal</a>
</div>

<div id="introModal" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal>
<ul data-orbit>

  <li>
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    <p>Some content in here.</p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" />
  </li>

  <li>  
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    <p>A description goes in here. This slide is larger and should expand.</p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/600" />
  </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive that this will do it:

```
<script>
    $("#introModal").on("after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit opened", function (event, orbit) {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
        var active = $(this).find("li.active")
        if (active.length > 0) {
             $(this).find(".orbit-slides-container").height(active.innerHeight()+20);
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this as an extra class in the modal container:

        `<ul class="orbit-container orbit--modal">`

and with following css it all works fine (for me):

        `.orbit--modal {
            height: auto !important;
        }`

Much as I'm loathe to use '!important' I feel that in this instance it's not such a biggie. Plus I couldn't get any js solution to work.

Note this is for a Fdn 6.3.1 build.